# Foreach no se detiene

Tags: c#

hola   mi duda es que tengo  un foreach que  no se detiene :

```
foreach (var i in establecimientos)
                        {

                            foreach (var promocionPlantilla in plantillaHabilitados)
                            {
                                List<PromocionEstablecimientos> promocionEstablecimientos =
                                        (from pe in bd.PromocionEstablecimientos
                                         select pe)
                                        .Where(x => x.EstablecimientoId == i.EstablecimientoId
                                        && x.PromocionId == promocionPlantilla.PromocionId)
                                        .ToList();

                                if (promocionEstablecimientos.Count() <= 0) //No Existe
                                {
                                    //Creamos la promocion establecimiento
                                    PromocionEstablecimientos nuevo = new PromocionEstablecimientos();
                                    nuevo.PromocionEstablecimientoId = Guid.NewGuid();
                                    nuevo.PromocionId = promocionPlantilla.PromocionId;
                                    nuevo.EstablecimientoId = i.EstablecimientoId;
                                    nuevo.CodigoProducto = promocionPlantilla.CodigoProducto;
                                    nuevo.CodigoProductoBonificado = promocionPlantilla.CodigoProductoBonificado;
                                    nuevo.Habilitado = promocionPlantilla.Habiitado;


                                    bd.PromocionEstablecimientos.Add(nuevo);
                                }else
                                {
                                    PromocionEstablecimientos xy =
                                        (from pe in bd.PromocionEstablecimientos
                                         select pe)
                                        .Where(x => x.EstablecimientoId == i.EstablecimientoId
                                        && x.PromocionId == promocionPlantilla.PromocionId)
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

                                    if (xy != null)
                                    {
                                        xy.Habilitado = true;
                                        xy.CodigoProducto = promocionPlantilla.CodigoProducto;
                                        xy.CodigoProductoBonificado = promocionPlantilla.CodigoProductoBonificado;
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    bd.SaveChanges();
                }

                blResultado = true;
            }
```

se que esta bien porque en la bd agrega pero  el  el programa no se detiene .

Comment: Tienes dos foreach, ¿cual no se detiene?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner la cantidad de items dentro de **"establecimientos"** y multiplicarlo por el numero de items en **"plantillaHabilitados"**?,  ya que según en Numero de **establecimientos** recorrerá tantas veces la lista de **plantillaHabilitados**.

Al final siempre termina de recorrer la lista, siempre que otro método no este llenando alguna de las dos listas anteriores.

Saludos.